# how to use local_overrides_packages

Tags: android, makefile

today i start to use `local_overrides_packages`

i set it like these:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE       := init.target.power.rc
LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := init.qcom.power.rc
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS  := optional eng
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := ETC
LOCAL_SRC_FILES    := root/init.target.power.rc
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH  := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

(can be found here: https://github.com/faizauthar12/android_device_xiaomi_ferrari/blob/cm-13.0/rootdir/Android.mk)

so in this case `init.qcom.power.rc`is being overrides by `init.target.power.rc`
but i got 2 of them is being used..
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIOpE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
PACKAGES.$(LOCAL_MODULE).OVERRIDES := init.qcom.power.rc
```

Note that *LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES* works if its a *LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME*.

Since yours is a *LOCAL_MODULE*, the above should work (at least it worked in my case :) )